# Trying to pass data to container view with segue not working

Tags: ios, swift, segue, uicontainerview

I am trying to pass a users id to a container view by preparing for a segue

```
  override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "childSegue" {
        if let destinationVC = self.childViewControllers.first as? InterestCollectionController {
            destinationVC.currentUser = self.currentUser
        }
    }
}
```

however, this is not working.  I have my storyboard that looks like this. 
[storyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aX8L4.png) I have also tried using segue.destination as! InterestCollectionController and that did not work either.  From my understanding this is the way I should be passing data to my container view.  Any help is appreciated thanks!

Comment: write as if let destinationVC = segue.destinationViewCOntroller as? InterestCollectionController {
            destinationVC.currentUser = self.currentUser
        }

Comment: On the container view I am trying to print out the id to make sure it is passing properly however, I get the error unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an optional value.

Comment: do you have any userid in 'self.currentUser'. please check.

Comment: I do have a value in self.currentUser.

Comment: ok.. please check for 'currentUser' in your destination class. Have you marked as Optional? If Yes, then please make it as a non-option say var myString =  String() in your destination class

Comment: Ah I see what you are saying, perhaps because the value is optional it tries to pass the data before I can give it a value?

Comment: I think Yes [as i don't know what you have written :) ]. Please try to make it as non-optional if it is optional.

Comment: It turns out it is because self.currentUser is actually nil, so I think I understand my problem now thank you.

Comment: great . welcome

Answer (score 1):

Just try this without using if statement:

```
 override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "childSegue" {
            let destinationVC = segue.destinationViewController as InterestCollectionController
            destinationVC.currentUser = self.currentUser

        }
     }
```

**1. Make sure your segue identifier matches with storyboard identifier.**

**2. Also verify once you have given exact segue to the above mentioned controller in storyboard.**

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
var destinationVC : InterestCollectionController?

 override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if (segue.identifier == "childSegue") {
            self.destinationVC = segue.destination as? InterestCollectionController
            destinationVC.currentUser = self.currentUser
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I tested that the view of the embedded view controller is not loaded, in other words, the `viewDidLoad()` was not invoked, before the containerVC's `prepare()` was called.

Therefore, you cannot directly pass data to the destination view controller inside the prepare() function.

Comment: So the prepare() in your base view controller is called by first, then your embedded view is loaded, finally your base view is loaded. Considering the order of execution, you can find that the right place to pass data to your embedded view is in viewDidLoad() of your base view controller. You can get the instance of your embedded view controller like this: "if let childVC = self.children.first as? ChildViewController { ...", then you get the chance to pass data.